# How is TF calculated in Sklearn

Tags: python-2.7, nlp, scikit-learn

I have been experimenting with sklearn's `Tfidfvectorizer`.
I am only concerned with TF, and not idf, so my settings have `use_idf = FALSE`
Complete settings are:

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5, max_features= n_features,
                         ngram_range=(1,3), use_idf=False)
```

I have been trying to replicate the output of `.fit_transform` but haven't managed to do it so far and was hoping someone could explain the calculations for me.

My toy example is:

```
document = ["one two three one four five",
            "two six eight ten two"]

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer, CountVectorizer
n_features = 5
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(max_df=0.5, max_features= n_features,
                             ngram_range=(1,3), use_idf=False)

X = vectorizer.fit_transform(document)

count = CountVectorizer(max_df=0.5, max_features= n_features,
                             ngram_range=(1,3))
countMat = count.fit_transform(document)
```

I have assumed the counts from the Count Vectorizer will be the same as the counts used int he Tfidf Vectorizer. So am trying to change the countMat object to match X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had missed a line from the documentation which says

> Each row is normalized to have unit euclidean norm

So to anwer my own question - the answer is:

```
for i in xrange(countMat.toarray().__len__()):
    row = countMat.toarray()[i]
    row / np.sqrt(np.sum(row**2))
```

Although I am sure there is a more elegant way to code the result.